# What exactly should be set in PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python

I'm going through and writing a setup doc for other developers at work for a python project and I've been reading up on the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. I'm looking at my current development system and think I have a few things set wrong that is causing my IDE (IntelliJ) to behave incorrectly when looking up the python libraries.

I've looked at the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859594/cant-find-my-pythonpath/859672#859672) and I'm still unsure of what should actually be in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

I have `PYTHONHOME` pointed to `C:\Python27`.

My current `PYTHONPATH` is set to `PYTHONHOME`. Should I also add the directories from `sys.path`?

**UPDATE**:

Based on the below information, `PYTHONPATH` does not need to be set unless there are non-standard libraries that you want python to be able to find by default. For instance, when I install [wxPython](https://www.wxpython.org) from the installer it will add its libraries to `PYTHONPATH`. I do set `PYTHONHOME` to the root of the python installation so that I can add it to my system `PATH` environment variable so that I can run python from any where.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You don't have to set either of them.  `PYTHONPATH` can be set to point to additional directories with private libraries in them.  `PYTHONHOME` sets the location of default libraries.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables):

> **PYTHONHOME**
> Change the location of the standard Python libraries. By default, the libraries are searched in *prefix*/lib/python*version* and *exec_prefix*/lib/python*version*, where *prefix* and *exec_prefix* are installation-dependent directories, both defaulting to /usr/local.
>
> When `PYTHONHOME` is set to a single directory, its value replaces both *prefix* and *exec_prefix*. To specify different values for these, set `PYTHONHOME` to *prefix:exec_prefix*.
>
> **PYTHONPATH**
> Augment the default search path for module files. The format is the same as the shell’s `PATH`: one or more directory pathnames separated by `os.pathsep` (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on Windows). Non-existent directories are silently ignored.
>
> In addition to normal directories, individual PYTHONPATH entries may refer to zipfiles containing pure Python modules (in either source or compiled form). Extension modules cannot be imported from zipfiles.
>
> The default search path is installation dependent, but generally begins with *prefix*/lib/python*version* (see `PYTHONHOME` above). It is always appended to `PYTHONPATH`.
>
> An additional directory will be inserted in the search path in front of `PYTHONPATH` as described above under `Interface options`. The search path can be manipulated from within a Python program as the variable `sys.path`.

Comment: PYTHONHOME actually points to the directory of the standard library by default (e.g. /usr/local/lib/pythonXX).

Comment: @Ferdinand Not on Windows.  It isn't set.  But the point is the user usually doesn't have to mess with either of them unless they have a private directory of libraries different that the defaults.

Comment: Of course it is not set -- Python never sets environment variables.  But there is an internal equivalent to PYTHONHOME that can be *overridden* using the environment variable.  I'm talking about the default value of this internal variable.

Comment: @"Ferdinand Beyer" "Of course it is not set -- Python never sets environment variables.", Well the latest _python 3.3_ at least can add itself to the PATH variable. Worthy of note.

Comment: @twobob *python 3.3* cannot add itself to the PATH variable, it is the *Python 3.3 installer* that does so, and that installer is not executing any Python code when it does.

Answer (score 28):

For most installations, you should not set these variables since they are not needed for Python to run.  Python knows where to find its standard library.

The only reason to set PYTHONPATH is to maintain directories of custom Python libraries that you do not want to install in the global default location (i.e., the `site-packages` directory).

Make sure to read: http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables

Comment: ok so you should not. But what SHOULD you do?! You want to run modules in the path, and don't want the source code holding paths (not relative and definitely not static paths).

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I learned: PYTHONPATH is a directory to add to the Python import search path "sys.path", which is made up of current dir. CWD, PYTHONPATH, standard and shared library, and customer library. For example:

```
% python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
['', 
'/home/username/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mySite', 
'/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

where the first path '' denotes the current dir., the 2nd path is via

```
%export PYTHONPATH=/home/username/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mySite
```

which can be added to ~/.bashrc to make it permanent, and the rest are Python standard and [dynamic shared library](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13192/what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-so-file) plus third-party library such as django.

As said not to mess with PYTHONHOME, even setting it to '' or 'None' will cause python3 shell to stop working:

```
% export PYTHONHOME=''
% python3
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f18a44ff740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Note that if you start a Python script, the CWD will be the script's directory.
For example:

```
username@bud:~/Documents/DjangoTutorial% python3 mySite/manage.py runserver
==== Printing sys.path ====
/home/username/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mySite # CWD is where manage.py resides
/usr/lib/python3.6
/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

You can also append a path to sys.path at run-time:
Suppose you have a file Fibonacci.py in ~/Documents/Python directory:

```
username@bud:~/Documents/DjangoTutorial% python3 
>>> sys.path.append("/home/username/Documents")
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', 
'/home/username/Documents']
>>> from Python import Fibonacci as fibo
```

or via

```
% PYTHONPATH=/home/username/Documents:$PYTHONPATH
% python3
>>> print(sys.path)
['', 
'/home/username/Documents', '/home/username/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mySite', 
'/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>>> from Python import Fibonacci as fibo
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit less 'ad hoc' solution than directly manipulating the `PYTHONPATH` exists with the use of the flag `-e` with the `pip` command, and allows to seamlessly install local libraries that can be imported, and re-imported to reflect changes made.

In order to be able to `import mypackage` the same way you do with any other module, the correct approach is to use pip locally:

`python -m pip install -e /path_to_package/mypackage/`

- `python -m` ensures you are using the pip package from the same `python` installation you are currently using.
- `-e` makes it editable, i/e `import mypackage` will reload after you make some changes, instead of using the cached one.

`mypackage` must be an installable package, i/e contain an `__init__.py`
file, and a basic `setup.py` (or `pyproject.toml` file for `pipenv`)

**minimal `setup.py`**

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='mypackage',          # Required
    version='0.0.1',           # Required
    packages=find_packages(),  # Required
)
```

**the package structure** must be like this:

```
mypackage/
    setup.py
    mypackage/    <----- this is a folder inside the other `mypackage/` folder
        __init__.py
```

or as a tree:

```
└── python_perso                folder
    └── mypackage                   folder
        ├── mypackage                   folder
        │   └── __init__.py
        └── setup.py
```

**[edit] after installation, the directory will look like this:**
(for a package named `mypackage`)

```
└── python_perso
    └── mypackage
        ├── mypackage
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── __pycache__
        │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
        ├── mypackage.egg-info
        │   ├── PKG-INFO
        │   ├── SOURCES.txt
        │   ├── dependency_links.txt
        │   └── top_level.txt
        └── setup.py

5 directories, 7 files
```

Comment: The `-e` option *doesn't* do any auto-reload! It just means that your package's files will be used from the place where they are, instead of copying them over to `site-packages` directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "restarting kernel"?
When you restart your script, the newly launched Python process will import modules from their declared paths. If you `pip install`ed your module without `-e` option then your files are copied from wherever they were to `site-packages` directory and loaded from there. If you edited your files then `site-packages` copy won't be edited until you re-install again with `pip install`.

Comment: Now, when you use `pip install -e` (aka `--editable`), pip will create a special file in `site-packages` named `MYMODULE.egg-link` with a full path to your module's original location (like `/home/user/work/mymodule`), and Python will load module files from there. So if you edit your module files then **any subsequent fresh import** will use the updated files, without you having to `pip install` again for updating the `site-packages` copy.
It should be noted though that `import`s are cached, so they won't be "auto-updated" until you restart Python process or use `importlib.reload`.

Comment: Thank you for these important precisions, you've explained it better than I.