# How can I edit PYTHONPATH on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, settings, command-line-interface

How can I permanently change the PYTHONPATH on a mac? I've tried editing .bash_profile, but when I use `print sys.path` in a file it gives a huge list of different URLs than the .bash_profile. In Terminal when I type `echo $PYTHONPATH` it shows a blank line. I don't want to use sys.path.append('...') because then I have to put that in every file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You can append the path to `$PATH` and not to [`$PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).
2. if you insist to change the `PYTHONPATH`, in some context that is
   prefferable:

   do [this](http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath):

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/username/pymodules
   ```
3. To make sure you are following the convention of what to append to
   `PYTHONPATH` see
   [What exactly should be set in PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850908/what-exactly-should-be-set-in-pythonpath).