# python: import module failure under non-root directory

Tags: python, python-import

I installed the oauth2 library, because I need to use the `oauth2.clients.imap` module, but then I found that only under root directory can I `import oauth2.clients.imap`. If I try to import this module under another directory, I got the error `ImportError: No module named clients.imap`.

Comment: Is `oauth2` in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa: Sorry I was unaware of the existence of PYTHONPATH. I called `echo $PYTHONPATH` and it is empty. Should I add the path of the `oauth2` to `PYTHONPATH` according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742779/how-can-i-edit-pythonpath-on-a-mac?

Comment: Yes, do this, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Vacation9: I did according http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x. But I am still not sure what the path mean here. Should it be the path of the directory of oauth2?

Comment: Add the location of the compiled python module code for `oauth2` to your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @Vacation9: how can I know the location of the complied python module code for `oauth2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth/
```