# How to INCLUDE code located in another folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a piece of code located in a file (utils.py) in a folder different from the one my current script is located in.  I tried:

```
from "/Z/scripts/utils.py" import *
```

but it gives a syntax error.  Is there a way to "include" my own code located elsewhere other than the current folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import a module from a relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

Comment: if scripts folder has `__init__.py` file then you can use `from Z.scripts.utils import *`

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia Thanks.  `/` becomes `.`?  What happens if the path name contains periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add that directory to your python path

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Z/")
from scripts.utils import *
```

Make sure the scripts directory contains an `__init__.py` file

Comment: This assumes there is a `__init__.py` in /Z/scripts , which may not be the case. Why wouldn't you recommend `sys.path.append("/Z/scripts"); from utils import *`?

Answer (score 0):

You can import code that is in a directory if it is added to `PYTHONPATH`. [See here for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850908/what-exactly-should-be-set-in-pythonpath)