# Current directory in Python module search path not working for django-admin

Tags: python, django

I was studying a document on [Django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/). It reminds us that the settings module should be on the Python import search path. So I added the following two lines to .bashrc as suggested in [here](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html):

```
-dell:~/Documents/DjangoTutorial$ tail -2 ~/.bashrc
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
-dell:~/Documents/DjangoTutorial$ . ~/.bashrc
```

and "django-admin runserver" is working from anywhere, with sys.path in Python3.7 showing:

```
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Then I read [article1](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html) and [article2](https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/python-import/) which imply that "sys.path" consists of : current dir.(denoted as ''), PYTHONPATH, standard and installed libraries. So I invoked django-admin strictly from the PYTHONPATH directory but commented out "#export PYTHONPATH" in ./bashrc and got an error as shown below:

```
-dell:~/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite$ django-admin runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
**ModuleNotFoundError**: No module named 'mysite'
```

I then checked sys.path and '' was there:

```
-dell:~/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite$ python3
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

My question is that if '' is equal to PYTHONPATH in this case and why cannot it find the settings module?

Comment: I'm not sure if you know how bashrc works, but please ensure you restart your terminal every time you change it. It is run every time you start it.

Answer (score 1):

From [sys.path definition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) and [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850908/what-exactly-should-be-set-in-pythonpath/57837992#57837992):

As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the **directory containing the script** that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked **interactively** or if the script is read from standard input), path[0] is the **empty string**, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first. Notice that **the script directory is inserted before the entries inserted as a result of PYTHONPATH**.

In my case,

```
-dell:~/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite$ django-admin runserver
```

where the file abspath is /usr/local/bin/django-admin and listed as such

```
sys.path = [/usr/local/bin, ...]
```

whereas CWD = ~/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite is not listed in the sys.path and thus the module "mysite.settings" under ~/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite cannot be found.

With

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite
```

it's working because now it is listed in:

```
sys.path = [/usr/local/bin, /home/user/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite, ...]
```

That is why manage.py is recommended over django-admin as its path is same as the export PYTHONPATH's and you can run it from anywhere even without setting $PYTHONPATH as it's duplicated below.

```
-dell:~/Documents/DjangoTutorial% mysite/manage.py runserver --noreload
sys.path = [
/home/user/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite # CWD = manage.py's path
/home/user/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite # export $PYTHONPATH's
...]
```