# Why is Globus Connect Personal not working?

Tags: http, globus-toolkit

I am trying to install and configure Globus Connect Personal for Linux (i have a CentOS 8), following [this tutorial](https://docs.globus.org/how-to/globus-connect-personal-linux/). However, when I try to set up Globus connect personal by running `./globusconnectpersonal -start` i get this error

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'gc.py'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = ''
  sys.base_prefix = '/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1599203911753/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1599203911753/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho'
  sys.executable = ''
  sys.prefix = '/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1599203911753/_h_env_placehold_
Subprocess pid 1722896 exited, rc=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gc-ctrl.py", line 369, in <module>
    start(debug=False)
  File "./gc-ctrl.py", line 191, in start
    send2clients(fds[2:], mesg.encode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

does anybody know what this could mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there needs to be PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH. I created a [conda environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) with just the correct version of python in it. Then I ran ./globusconnectpersonal inside the conda environment.

Using a conda environment also works for the non-GUI form of globus.

I have not tried [setting the paths manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850908/what-exactly-should-be-set-in-pythonpath).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I was using Python3.8 in a Miniconda environment. When I disabled conda with:

```
conda deactivate
```

Then I could run "globusconnectpersonal -start" with my native Python2.7. I don't know if it was because the client needed Python2 or if conda was interfering, but his resolved the problem for me.