# Problems with importing modules in Python

Tags: python

So this problem took already so much time in my life that I would really much would like to solve this once and for all. I changed the directories in my project and now everything is broken again, so what is the best way to solve this? My structure is like this:

```
MYPROJECT
|
-- src
    |
   -- data
       __init__.py
       basic_script.py
   -- utils
      __init__.py
      some_utils.py
```

basic_script.py needs some functions from some_utils.py. I import these with

```
'import utils.some_utils as some_utils
```

The root in my terminal is 'c:\some_path\MYPROJECT.
I run the file with

```
'python src/data/basic_script.py'
```

Now I had everything working , but I changed the root directory and now I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

So i can try to solve this over the coming hours, but I would like to know how to avoid this in the future:

1. what exactly do I have to add to my python path?
2. is this the way to solve this, or can it be done in a better way?
3. If I transfer the whole project to a different system, what is the way to make it work again? Can this be done with a setup.py? If yes, how exactly?

My sys.path currently only contains all python versions and 'c:\projects\MYPROJECT\.venv'

thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 0):

> I changed the directories in my project and now everything is broken again, so what is the best way to solve this?

It seems like you already figured that out, but for completeness' sake:
The problem here is most likely that your `utils` package is not in the `PYTHONPATH`. That's a list of directories that Python will search when looking for modules to import.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850908/what-exactly-should-be-set-in-pythonpath) for more details.

1. You add the path to your `src` folder. Assuming Powershell, you can probably use `$Env:PYTHONPATH += ';c:\some_path\MYPROJECT\src'`.[^1]
2. See "Quick fix:" later.
3. Yes. **Read the docs** for [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/) or another packaging software of your choice. It's somewhat involved, ask another question if you get stuck.

Quick fix: Use an IDE that manages you `PYTHONPATH` and updates your imports as you move modules around. (I like PyCharm)

[1]: I don't use Windows, so better refer to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables) for powershell.